# Sankey chart - How to Control the width and position of node separately using Amchart or any other JS library

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts4

I am working on a chart implementation using [Amcharts Js library](https://www.amcharts.com/) and I faced two issues

- First one is that each node need to have a different width, currently using Amcharts you can only adjust the width to all nodes together.
- Second issue that I need to push some of the node in the first level a little bit depending on time factor but using Am chart all the nodes in one level start from the same X point.

[image]

I am open to use any other JS library or other techniques to achieve this same result.

**Note: That only nodes one level one need adjustment if we start level from 0.**

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dark);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.SankeyDiagram);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data = [
  { from: "A", to: "E", value: 1, id:"A0-0" },
  { from: "A", to: "F", value: 1, id:"A1-0" },
  { from: "A", to: "G", value: 1, id:"A2-0" },
  
  { from: "B", to: "E", value: 1, id:"B0-0" },
  { from: "B", to: "F", value: 1, id:"B1-0" },
  { from: "B", to: "G", value: 1, id:"B2-0" },  
  
  { from: "C", to: "F", value: 1, id:"C0-0" },
  { from: "C", to: "G", value: 1, id:"C1-0" },
  { from: "C", to: "H", value: 1, id:"C2-0" },    

  { from: "D", to: "E", value: 1, id:"D0-0" },
  { from: "D", to: "F", value: 1, id:"D1-0" },
  { from: "D", to: "G", value: 1, id:"D2-0" },      
  { from: "D", to: "H", value: 1, id:"D3-0" },        

  { from: "E", to: "I", value: 1, id:"A0-1" },
  { from: "E", to: "I", value: 1, id:"B0-1" },      
  { from: "E", to: "L", value: 1, id:"D0-1" },          

  { from: "F", to: "I", value: 1, id:"A1-1" },
  { from: "F", to: "I", value: 1, id:"C0-1" },      
  { from: "F", to: "I", value: 1, id:"D1-1" },          
  { from: "F", to: "M", value: 1, id:"B1-1" },          

  { from: "G", to: "I", value: 1, id:"A2-1" },
  { from: "G", to: "I", value: 1, id:"B2-1" },      
  { from: "G", to: "J", value: 1, id:"C1-1" },          
  { from: "G", to: "N", value: 1, id:"D2-1" },  

  { from: "H", to: "K", value: 1, id:"C2-1" },          
  { from: "H", to: "N", value: 1, id:"D3-1" },    

  { from: "I", to: "O", value: 1, id:"A0-2" },
  { from: "I", to: "O", value: 1, id:"B2-2" },      
  { from: "I", to: "Q", value: 1, id:"A1-2" },          
  { from: "I", to: "R", value: 1, id:"A2-2" },          
  { from: "I", to: "S", value: 1, id:"D1-2" },
  { from: "I", to: "T", value: 1, id:"B0-2" },          
  { from: "I", to: "Q", value: 1, id:"C0-2" },          

  { from: "J", to: "U", value: 1, id:"C1-2" },            
  
  { from: "K", to: "V", value: 1, id:"C2-2" },              
  { from: "M", to: "U", value: 1, id:"B1-2" },                

  { from: "N", to: "Q", value: 1, id:"D2-2" },                
  { from: "N", to: "Q", value: 1, id:"D3-2" },

  { from: "L", to: "W", value: 1, id:"D0-2" }
];

let hoverState = chart.links.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 0.6;

chart.dataFields.fromName = "from";
chart.dataFields.toName = "to";
chart.dataFields.value = "value";

chart.links.template.propertyFields.id = "id";
chart.links.template.colorMode = "solid";
chart.links.template.fill = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet().getFor("alternativeBackground");
chart.links.template.fillOpacity = 0.1;
chart.links.template.tooltipText = "";

// highlight all links with the same id beginning
chart.links.template.events.on("over", function(event){
  let link = event.target;
  let id = link.id.split("-")[0];

  chart.links.each(function(link){
    if(link.id.indexOf(id) != -1){
      link.isHover = true;
    }
  })
})

chart.links.template.events.on("out", function(event){  
  chart.links.each(function(link){
    link.isHover = false;
  })
})

// for right-most label to fit
chart.paddingRight = 30;

// make nodes draggable
var nodeTemplate = chart.nodes.template;
nodeTemplate.inert = true;
nodeTemplate.readerTitle = "Drag me!";
nodeTemplate.showSystemTooltip = true;
nodeTemplate.width = 20;

// make nodes draggable
var nodeTemplate = chart.nodes.template;
nodeTemplate.readerTitle = "Click to show/hide or drag to rearrange";
nodeTemplate.showSystemTooltip = true;
nodeTemplate.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

body { background-color: #30303d; color: #fff; }
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dark.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```